# str_getcsv not parsing the data correctly

Tags: php, string, csv, explode, fgetcsv

I have a problem with str_getcsv function for PHP.

I have this code:

```
<?php
$string = '#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=714000,RESOLUTION=640x480,CODECS="avc1.77.30, mp4a.40.34"';

$array = str_getcsv($string, ",", '"');

print_r($array);
```

Which should return:

```
Array
(
    [0] => #EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1
    [1] => BANDWIDTH=714000
    [2] => RESOLUTION=640x480
    [3] => CODECS=avc1.77.30, mp4a.40.34
)
```

But instead, it is returning:

```
Array
(
    [0] => #EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1
    [1] => BANDWIDTH=714000
    [2] => RESOLUTION=640x480
    [3] => CODECS="avc1.77.30
    [4] =>  mp4a.40.34"
)
```

Cause it is ignoring the enclosure of the last parameter: CODECS and is spliting also that information. I'm using str_getcsv instead of just doing explode(",", $string) precisely for that reason (that function should respect the enclosure) but it is working the same as explode will do it.

The code being executed: http://eval.in/17471

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *enclosure* (third) parameter does not have quite that effect. The enclosure character is treated as such only when it appears next to the delimiter.

To get your desired output, the input would need to be

```
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,...,"CODECS=avc1.77.30, mp4a.40.34"
```

**[See it in action](http://eval.in/17472)**.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I'm receiving that information from a m3u8 file. Is there any easy way to get the information as I wanted?

Comment: @AbrahamSustaita: `str_replace('CODECS="', '"CODECS=', $line)` would let you go home early. Impure as hell but you can't argue with the practicality.